# $.ajax url string prevent automatic encoding

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, get

I've coded this:

```
var serviceURL = "..../MaterialCollection(MaterialID='" + materialID + "')";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: serviceURL,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: callbackSuccess,
    error: callbackError,
});
```

The thing is that serviceURL is getting automatically encoded, that is `(` is translated to `%28` and `)` is translated to `%29`.
I don't want this URL to be automatically encoded.
What am I supposed to do?

Thank you.
Regards

Comment: What browser is this under? How are you testing it? Chrome sends the request to the proper URL.

Comment: at which point it is "automatically encoded", and why do you think that is an issue?

Comment: Chrome, latest released. It's encoded in the browser when I click on Network traffic I can see the URL is encoded.

Comment: so why is that an issue? it should be encoded according to the URI spec - if it isn't, IIRC it's a violation of specifications. See [rfc 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.4) "Once produced, a URI is always in its percent-encoded form."

Comment: it's an issue because my back-end server doesn't read that format. It expects ( ) and not %28 and %29. In between my client and the back-end server, there's a ProxyServlet (JEE6 - cloud) which redirects to my back-end. I might be able to translate the URI back to ( )  (i.e. decode the URI which I'm getting from AJAX) but I don't like it. I would like AJAX not to make this automatic translation. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Why you don't like to decode it? That encoded URL is correct and you have to decode it. That's it.